# jquery + asp.net delay postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, postback

I would like to implement a slideUp jQuery effect on LinkButton click and then do postback on page. The effect takes 600ms to accomplish. The problem I confront with is that before jQuery effect finishes page already does postback, so the jQuery script stops somewhere halfway. Is there any way to delay postback other then doing a manual postback?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to provide a function to slideup which will only execute when the sliding is done:

```
formDiv.slideUp('normal', function () {
    $(form).submit();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the call to load/reload the page in the callback function of the `slideUp` animation.

Something like:

```
$("#myElement").click(function() {
    $("#otherElement").slideUp(600, function() {
        // $("#form").submit(); // or
        // window.location.assign("mypage.aspx");
    });
})
```

If you could post your code I can show you in more detail.

Comment: The probelem is that we don't want to use custom postback and I seek a way to delay standard postback.
This is my LinkButton code:
OnClientClick="var thisPage = new HomePage(); thisPage.slideUp(); " OnClick="TestLinkButton_Click">Test</asp:LinkButton>

JS:
function HomePage() {
}
HomePage.prototype.slideUp = function () {
    $(".welcome").slideUp(600).delay(2000);
}

I include the delay(2000) function only to show what behaviour I'd like to have. In this example execule the slideup and then doPostback. 
On the page I have a MultiView control and only want to switch between views.

Answer (score 0):

You can block the PostBack event with `return false`. Then invoke the PostBack of the button manually by calling `__doPostBack` with the correct LinkButton name by using it's `UniqueID`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        //do stuff
        setTimeout(function () { delayedPostBack(); }, 1000);
    }

    function delayedPostBack() {
        __doPostBack('<%= LinkButton1.UniqueID %>', '');
    }
</script>

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="myFunction(); return false;" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```