# Postback occuring before Jquery SlideUp animation

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am having an issue where the animation of the slideUp method in JQuery is not working due to the postback occurring before the animation has finished.

I have got the following code in my aspx file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SlideUp() {
    $('.sectionPanel').slideUp("slow", function () { return true; });
}
</script>

<asp:LinkButton runat="server"  CssClass="sideTab" OnClientClick="return SlideUp();" OnClick="SideMenuTab_OnClick" >Breach Details</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="sideTab"  OnClick="SideMenuTab_OnClick" OnClientClick="return SlideUp();">Additional</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="uxPanel1" CssClass="sectionPanel" style="background-color:Yellow;">
Panel 1
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="uxPanel2" CssClass="sectionPanel" style="background-color: Red;">
Panel 2
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: why do you wan to slideup after you have triggered a postback?
A postback terminates everything.

Comment: I am trying to get the animation to occur before the Postback is fired, but it seems the Postback is firing before the JQuery animation is finished.

Comment: I just found an similar question to what i am also after achieving, but in his post it still hasn't been answered

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397545/jquery-asp-net-delay-postback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the PostBack of the LinkButton by always returning `false`.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" OnClientClick="SlideUp(); return false;">Breach Details</asp:LinkButton>
```

Then you can initiate the button click by calling it's PostBack event in a delay with `__doPostBack`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SlideUp() {
        $('.sectionPanel').slideUp("slow");
        setTimeout(function () { fakePostBack(); }, 1500);
    }

    function fakePostBack() {
        __doPostBack('<%= LinkButton1.UniqueID %>', '');
    }
</script>
```

This requires that the LinkButton has an `ID`, in your snippet they don't have one. You need this for the `UniqueID`.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider to use a delay in javascript before you return true. [link]http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: I have added the following but still not made any difference

$('.sectionPanel').slideUp("slow").delay(1600,function() { return true;});